# javascript undefined elements occurs during regex split

Tags: javascript, regex

The following code results in undefined element at the middle

```
"Hello World\n\nhello world".split(/\n(\n|\t|\s)*?\n/)
"Hello World\n\nhello world".split(/\n(\n|\t|\s)*\n/)
```

The output is

```
["Hello World", undefined, "hello world"]
```

I wanted to split if there were two new line characters with any number of new line or space or tab character between them as long as they are not alphabets or symbols or numbers.

Comment: I think you want `/\n\s*\n/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because when you use a capture group in a split pattern, javascript includes the content of the capture group in the result. Since, the capture group can't be empty, it is never repeated, that's why you get "undefined" and not an empty string.

To prevent this, use a non-capturing group or a character class:

```
"Hello World\n\nhello world".split(/\n(?:\n|\t|\s)*\n/)
"Hello World\n\nhello world".split(/\n\s*\n/) # (\t and \n are already included in \s)
```

Note: if you want to remove leading and trailing spaces too, you can use:

```
/(?:[^\S\n]*\n){2}\s*/
```

Answer (score 6):

Use a [non-capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions) to prevent the contents of the capture group(s) from being included.

```
/\n(?:\n|\t|\s)*?\n/
```

It will return:

```
"Hello World\n\nhello world".split(/\n(?:\n|\t|\s)*?\n/);
// ["Hello World", "hello world"]
```